# is it possible to perform a get action in a post request and post action in get request

Tags: http, post, get

Is it possible to do a get request and treat it as a post request on the server side and vice versa. I know it doesn't make a sense to do so, but is it possible technically. Could there be any issues since I think it is technically very much possible.

For eg:
do a POST processing on the server side(create a resource for eg), using get type of request from client which will have a body as it is possible for a GET request to have a body.

Comment: What do you mean by “treat it as a POST request”? The verb isn’t your problem, it’s that the payloads will be sent differently by the client (notably a POST will likely have a body). But otherwise it’s not really any different to HTTP. Can you elaborate and/or do you have a specific use case?

Comment: do a POST processing on the server side(create a resource for eg), using get type of request from client which will have a body

Comment: A GET while technically allowed to have a body, it is not allowed to affect the request (and many browsers and libraries will drop or disallow it) so do not expect it to work. Also remember that GET requests can and often are cached by proxies, caching servers, and browsers, which can make things like this unpredictable.

Comment: If you can pass everything in the query string (don’t forget that many things log the entire request string and parameters, so this can expose sensitive data) and take appropriate measures to try and prevent caching, you can get this to work, but I wouldn’t unless I had no other choice.

Comment: this question is not abt a choice, but its about whether its possible or not. And I know some reputed products which send body in a GET request, and when you can do this, you can as well use that body to do a POST processing on the server. What do you do if your GET request is very complex and cannot fit in request params or request path

Comment: You can’t use a body with GET in any reliable way. And if it doesn’t fit you use POST.

Comment: and then you do GET in a POST request which was my second query..